# R Accessing vector element within a list

Tags: r

So I have a list (a1) of length two with a vector within each list element. Here is a simplified version.

```
a1 <- list(c(0, 1, 2), c(3, 4, 5))
```

How can I access an element within the vector of a list?

Like if I want to grab the number 2, i've tried the following without luck.

```
a1[1,][3]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the first code block to have valid R code. I'm guessing this should be something like `a1 <- list(c(0, 1, 2), c(3, 4, 5))`

Comment: Use double brackets for the first level, and single for the second, e.g. `a1[[1]][3]` will give you 2, `a1[[2]][2]` will give you 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
a1[[1]][3]
```

`a1` has only a single dimension, so there is no need for a comma.  Since `a1` is a list, selecting `a1[1]` is a list of length 1 containing the vector `c(0, 1, 2)`.  To get into the list, you need the second set of braces (`a1[[1]]`).

Comment: Is it any different if instead of it being a vector, it is another list?

Comment: Yes.  If the contents of `a1` is another list, you would need to access the third entry as `a1[[1]][[3]]`

Comment: I used the `typeof()` function to see what it was and it turns out it is a list within `a1` but when I try to do the `[[x]][[y]]` it gives me `Error in .subset2(x, i) : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: You need to clarify your question then - I'm not sure how to help you. 
 What is `y`?  how long is the list `y` is trying to access?  What did you call `typeof` on?  Please provide more details on exactly what you are doing and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, I guess what I thought was a list within my list was actually a string that was just separated by commas which would explain why what you were explaining wasn't working. Thanks for the help!